# 80s/90s anime with three robots waken up, and had to be taken down by another robot because they weren't good

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm looking for a title of an old 80's/early 90's anime featuring large robots.

What I can remember is that there were 3 (I think) buried.  Something woke them up, they weren't good... and I think maybe a good robot had to take them down.

I remember one had kind of large blades... could possibly create strong winds.  I think he was green white and black?

Comment: What have you already done in an effort to find this anime? Are there any possibilities we can *rule out,* at least?

Comment: I feel like ive seen the @rse end of google.  Ive ruled out any mainstream series or films thats for sure.  Its defo a one off

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 1):

Beast King GoLion, had several robots/mecha deactivated or standying by in several planets, but I dont know if these were buried.

Answer (score 1):

Is this The Big O? Giant black Megadeuse mecha with some red parts piloted by Roger Smith, the main protagonist. Fights other Megadeuses that were buried from time and “wake up” and appear in the city. One was green, gold, and white with some purple highlights.

One had the ability to generate wind, another had drill bits for arms, another could fly.